# Automated way to sort annotations alphabetically?

Tags: java, formatting

we have some interfaces defining larger number of constants; and on each of the constants we have some 3 to 5 (or more) annotations. Us usual with such things, different people are adding stuff; and all of a sudden it looks like topsy-turvy.

We are already using a customized eclipse formatter ... but I couldn't find any option there that would reorder annotations (to be in alphabetical order).

Searching the net also didn't show any other tool able to do that.

Any idea, anybody?

(reasoning behind that: having those many annotations; and each list in slightly different order makes it very hard to grasp things like "he, this guy should have @whatever, too". if all lists would be sorted, my hope is to spot such oversights faster)

Comment: Do you want to sort them alphabetically once and then ask the developers to respect the order or being able to never care about the order and automatically reorder before each commit ?

Comment: @Dici Sure, that is one way; and if I don't come up with something better; probably the only way. But in general, formatting (and probably "checking for such kind of rules") is better automated. That is one of the essential things in IT: if you have to do something more than once, automate it.

Comment: I mean, you could sort them once using code, not manually. I don't know any simple way to reformat code in such ways, but it is fairly easy to write something which reformats all the files once, and then leaves the order up to the devs

Comment: Yeah still missing this feature.